# How to migrate data from MongoDB to Oracle using c#

Tags: c#, oracle, mongodb

I have some c# experience, I just need a nudge in the right direction?(the easy one) I have seen a lot of people asking to migrate from Oracle to MongoDB but nothing for MongoDB to Oracle so my first question : 
1. Is it possible?
2. Should i use C# driver for MongoDB ?
3. Is there any example code out there?

I want to use c# to achieve the migration.

Thanx in advance

Comment: 1. Yes it's possible (*very few* things are impossible); 2. You have to use *.Net* driver (you have to *read the data* at least). 3. Try using *Google*

Comment: Another hint: use the right tool for the job.  Actually, it should be pretty easy: Use an ODM to read the data, use an ORM to write the data.